# Calling Dispose will not clean up the memory used by an object C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

One gut told me that Dispose is meant to be used to run user defined code that releases resources that are not automatically released - like file handles, network handles, database connections etc.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

### he said also

Note, .NET garbage collector is quite unpredictable and it might create a few instances of an object before cleaning up all the older instances that were eligible for collection. A way to know for sure (without resorting to memory profilers) is to put a breakpoint in the finalizer.

i through the above GC related code free up the memory and collect all unclaimed object or the object goes out of scope.

also he said never use the above GC related code in production environment but did not explain the reason why....so tell me what will be harm if anyone use these below GC related code  `GC.Collect();` `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();  GC.Collect();`

anyway looking for in-depth knowledge. thanks

Comment: TL;DR: because the whole point of having a runtime that automatically manages memory is to not have to do that. If you try to take over you had better know what you are doing **very well**, because it's almost certain that you are going to make things worse.

Comment: Never use GC by yourself if you aring sure what you're doing. Children aint allowed to play with fire :)

Comment: Dispose() and GC.Collect() are largely unrelated.

Comment: so i understand that people should not use but like to know when people use GC.Collect(); and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); thanks

Comment: @Jon Agreed. However, this is not a good philosophy when dealing with memory hungry applications in which you would want to minimize GC runs etc. Understanding how something works is just as important as knowing not to mess with it :D

Comment: @Alex: "This is a complicated subject; you have to be an expert before tweaking things" is IMO a very good philosophy on all complicated subjects, so I 'm not sure what you mean. It's also not clear to me how explicitly causing collections is going to minimize GC runs. If anything, in most cases it will *increase* them.

Comment: @Jon Fair point. I wasn't saying causing GC runs is a good thing. I meant exactly the opposite. But like you said it's an expert's realm...and expert I'm not. Still I like complicating things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GC` never calls `Dispose` method, as soon as you do it manually in finalizer

The workflow of `GC` is pretty simple, but a lot of people get confused, let's put things to their places

`Dispose` is not related to `GC`. `Dispose` is a method, that is defined in interface `IDisposable`, and like other interfaces, classes can implement that method and give users ability to call that method. GC doesn't pay attention to this interface at all. 
   As soon as we have an automatic memory management in .NET, and we know that GC does his job well, and it clears all managed resources automatically, accordingly there is no reason to provide user `Dispose` method for clearing managed resources. So generally Dispose is used for clearing unmanaged resources, but no one prevents you to unsubscribe from global events as an example, or call Dispose for nested objects (note that global events are almost always bad practice :))

On the other hand, `GC` knows about `Finalizer`, and if `Finalizer` exists `GC` postpones object disposition until next collection, and call `Finalizer` before clearing memory. To have disposition code in one place, programmers usually create `Dispose(bool)` and call this method from `Finalizer` and `IDisposable.Dispose` method. Here you need to be aware that you are not allowed to access managed resources, if the call come from Finalizer, because GC doesn't guarantee any disposition order, and that resources might already be in invalid state. This is called [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Regarding GC call in production, yes it is not recommended, again because generally GC does his work well, and since GC.Collect is expensive operation, there is no reason to bother with GC engine, before we decide to do automatic collection.

Comment: thanks for reply. u said GC.Collect is expensive opperation. will mind to explain a bit when it is expensive? thanks

Comment: Always, it starts in it's own thread, uses processor time and computer memory, to analyze object graph, stops threads that are using this or those object references, calls finalizers and etc. Agree, in .net GC is pretty fast, but however GC doesn't have 0 impact on performance. In .NET 2 and .NET 1.1, I remember, WinForm applications stop to response from time to time for some short period(less than a second actually) and there were a gossip GC is the reason. In later version,true, the impact is not noticeable, but however not 0 too.